# Weird behavior of TextView.setGravity() in custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, viewgroup

I have a project where I need to programmatically create a `TextView` and place it inside a custom `ViewGroup`. When I instantiate the textView, I set its layoutParams, text, gravity etc, then add it to the `ViewGroup`. Then in the `onLayout()` method of the `ViewGroup` i try to position it (as recommended by google guidelines).
Everything is fine `EXCEPT` for the textView's text gravity. Only `center_horizontal` seems to work. The entire problem can be boiled down to a few lines of code as below:

```
public class Custom extends ViewGroup {
TextView mTv;
public Custom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mTv = new TextView(context);
    mTv.setText("can't touch this");
    mTv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mTv.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.paleblue));
    this.addView(mTv,params);
}

public Custom(Context context) {
    this(context,null);

}


@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    mTv.layout(l,t,r,b);
}}
```

And the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.apps.renegade.testbook.Custom
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: The text should be in the center of the screen.]

The text should be in the center of the screen. Can anyone explain why is this happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override a `ViewGroup`, check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), this is the official document which shows you how to extend a `ViewGroup`.